# Sitecore Google fonts not working in Production

Tags: css, fonts, sitecore, google-font-api

Google fonts are not working

```
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" 
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It's working fine on the local machine but in the production environment it's not working. I have published all the necessary files.

CSS :

```
body {
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Show sufficient code (including a complete, though preferably minimal, HTML document) that actually reproduces the issue, and tell what the issue is: does the content appear in wrongly formatted PT Sans Narrow, or in Arial, or in browser default font, or what? It is also crucial to identify the browser(s) tested. Make sure you include HTML code *as received by browsers*.

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing the Google URL without the URI scheme, i.e.

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If your target page is being loaded in HTTPS including the tag above will load the font over HTTPS as well.  Specifying HTTP as you have may prevent the loading of the resource by the browser when the rest of the page is being loaded under HTTPS.